# Handling Session time out in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, session, razor, global-asax

In my mvc3 (razor) application i want to handling session timeout by displaying a `popup` for `re entering User id and password`

How can i write it as common in  `Session_End()`  in `Global.asax`

Is it possible to `display a jquery model popup` from here

Is there any way to implement this without losing data please share..

Comment: displaying `jquery modal popup` from a `Session_End` .... is something I dont think is possible.

Comment: Avoid using seasion_end because the event does not fire if you deploy to muti web server environment. The action filter alone with combination of view logic to display login dialog should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with session_end in combination with an action filter and jquery.

1. Set `HttpContext.Current.Items['sessionEnded']` to true in `Session_End()`
2. Create an action filter which checks for that Item and set `ViewBag.SessionEnded` to true
3. In your layout trigger the javascript if `ViewBag.SessionEnded` is true.

Comment: if you dont mind could u please share about creating action filter

Comment: First hit in google for `c# create actionfilter`: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: couldn't  get HttpContext.Current in session_End(). it shows Object reference not set to an instance of an object.